# C# WCF NetTcpBinding timeout not working

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, nettcpbinding

I've got a problem with the NetTcpBinding's Open, Send, Recive and Close timeouts on the initial call(`[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = true)]`)
Currently I'm trying to connect to a given IPAddress and if it fails I will connect to a different address.
This is because I cannot connect to my own server through my external IP (due to NAT Loopback on my router?), and instead of having 2 versions (one for the public and one for myself) I use a Try-Catch system which tries to connect to my external IP, if it works -> continue, if it fails -> try local IP -> continue.

The problem however is the timeout values. Since I am waiting for an exception to be thrown and caught, I need to lower this value as much as possible (preferred 5sec) instead of the default ~20 seconds.

I've tried to set these values on both Client and Server side

```
tcpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
```

**Server side setup:**

```
svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceAssembly.ServiceImplementation));
NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();

tcpBinding.MaxConnections = 100;
tcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = (int)4096000;
tcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 4096000;
tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = (int)4096000;
tcpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel =
System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

svh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceAssembly.IChat),tcpBinding,"net.tcp://IPAddress:3100/MyService");

SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
svh.Open();
```

**Client side setup & call**

```
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);
NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();

tcpBinding.MaxConnections = 100;
tcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = (int)4096000;
tcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 4096000;
tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = (int)4096000;
tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
tcpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
tcpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;

tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel =
    System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
    TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

 try
 {
      scf = new DuplexChannelFactory<IChat>(context, tcpBinding,
            "net.tcp://" + m_ipAddress + ":" + m_port + "/MyService");
      s = scf.CreateChannel(); 
      s.Connect(client); <- First connection
 }
 catch
 {
     try
     {
         scf = new DuplexChannelFactory<IChat>(context, tcpBinding,
               "net.tcp://" + m_localAddress + ":" + m_port + "/MyService");
         s = scf.CreateChannel();
         s.Connect(client);
         m_ipAddress = m_localAddress;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

But the timeout for the exception to be thrown is still around 20 seconds. Changing these values wont change the time until the exception is thrown. I have added an image below to show the call stack.
[image]
Any advice on how to do fix this or even make it better is wanted.

Comment: Are you sure its using the tcpbinding settings, eg, whats the bit more code round it, to show it being setup, and using this binding, and opened.

Comment: What excpetion is thrown?

Comment: @BugFinder see my edit.

Comment: @Helic It's in the image "System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException" which is expected.

Comment: Im thinking that the "OpenTimeout" is exactly that, if its not found, the dns and various other things that means that there is no endpoint to use is not covered by these timeouts, only that a connection that should work must connect wtihin this time limit.

Comment: @BugFinder so there is no way to reduce the time it takes? Is it a hardware issue perhaps?

Comment: It depends on a number of things I guess, dns lookups, and so forth.

Comment: @BugFinder hmn okay, I'll have to figure something out to handle it then. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found that helped me - not to remove this timeout, but to connect to my own server if local and/or connect over external IP if not - was to actually look for the process itself. If found -> Connect locally , else -> connect via the given IP.
This does not answer my actual question - however - it does solve my initial issue.
It seems that the TimeOut "delay" is due to the DNS and not something I can do to prevent it.

Here's my solution code if anyone's interested.

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName").Length > 0)
     isLocal = true;

 if (isLocal)
     scf = new DuplexChannelFactory<IChat>(context, tcpBinding,
           "net.tcp://" + m_localAddress + ":" + m_port + "/MyService");
 else
     scf = new DuplexChannelFactory<IChat>(context, tcpBinding,
           "net.tcp://" + m_ipAddress + ":" + m_port + "/MyService");
```